# the difference between nx and Lerna ? (monorepos)

Tags: javascript, monorepo, lerna, nrwl-nx, nrwl

hello i'm in new in monorepos world and i'm now searching about different monorepos tools
and i found two intersting tools Nx(nrwl) and lerna but i didn't understand the real differnce between  these two tools  so any help  and thanks

Answer (score 103, accepted):

## 2022 Update

As pointed out by my great fellow at the comment section, Lerna is now being held by the Nx team.

The best solution nowadays is to use more native approaches for publishing (as NPM/YARN workspaces) or go straight to Nx.

Good references:

- [Lerna is dead — Long Live Lerna](https://blog.nrwl.io/lerna-is-dead-long-live-lerna-61259f97dbd9)
- [Integrating Nx and Lerna](https://nx.dev/migration/lerna-and-nx)

## 2021 Answer (slightly outdated but still valid)

Although both are great tools to work with mono repo, they're quite different in their purpose.

### Differences

`Lerna` is focused on linking multiple packages from the same project and managing npm publishing, **and that's about it**.

`Nx` is more focused on managing **development workflow** for multiple packages. It means it can scaffold packages, and for every package, you can define configurations on how to run and build them, in a similar manner to Webpack.

`Nx` can also work to spawn multiple processes at once. For example: run frontend and backend at the same time, without the need to open two different terminals. Similar to docker-compose.

### Where they thrive

`Lerna` fits better for open source projects with multiple packages (because you can easily publish your packages).

`Nx` fits better for handling complex workflows with multiple packages.

### How to choose

- If you don't intend to publish your packages, `Nx` might be a better fit.
- If you do intend to publish then, but you don't have a complex workflow, `Lerna` is definitely the way to go.
- If you want both (publish **and** complex workflow), neither one seems great, but you should probably choose `Nx`, and manage the publishing manually. Or, maybe, use `Lerna` and configure the workflow manually with Webpack.

Someone can wonder if you could choose both, but I don't think they can work well together. At the time I'm writing this, `Nx` doesn't seem to care about being compatible with `Lerna`, and it `Nx` still lacks support for easy publishing.

### An important disclaimer about terminology

- I used the name "package" here because "package" is what you can publish on the internet (for example, as npm is a node **package** manager).
- `Lerna` uses the name "project" as the wrapper folder of all your packages. Usually, a git repository is a "Lerna project" with several "Lerna packages".
- `Nx` uses the name "project" to designate what Lerna calls "packages", and uses the name "workspace" to designate what Lerna calls "project" (i.e., the wrapper folder which holds all the projects).

Comment: I recently opted for NX, and what really helped me with publishing was a plugin for NX: https://github.com/jscutlery/semver

Comment: I decided to use lerna cause I want to create a monorepo for multiple dependencies that are going to be used in different projects

Comment: According to NX doc, it can work with Lerna. See this: https://nx.dev/migration/lerna-and-nx

Comment: Lerna and NX are now managed by the same team. Its now possible to use both in projects

https://blog.nrwl.io/lerna-is-dead-long-live-lerna-61259f97dbd9

Comment: Sorry to be so picky, but "NPM - Node Package Manager" is not correct. Check out the npm repo: https://github.com/npm/cli#is-npm-an-acronym-for-node-package-manager

Comment: wow I didn't know about that, that's for bringing it up. But I just did some research, and even though npm is not an acronym, npm is still a "node package manager", by their own words, as you can see at the home page: https://www.npmjs.com/#:~:text=node%20package%20manager

Comment: "Not going to be maintained" is contrary to Nrwl statements. A team from Nrwl is maintaining Lerna and recently released Lerna v5. Today, Nx uses Lerna and Lerna uses Nx.

Comment: They don't say it with these exact words, but by reading the article you can see this is the path Lerna is going to take in the future.